# Using PHP to build a TABLE from JSON results

Tags: php, html, json

I just started to learn PHP and I have managed to get JSON data back that I need but struggling to build a table from the JSON data. I know I am doing it totally wrong with trial and error, but stuck now.

The PHP I have so far:

```
<?php
  ............

  $domains = json_decode(get_option('cc_whmcs_bridge_tlds'), true);
  if (count($domains->pricing)) {
    // Open the table
    echo "<table>";

    // Cycle through the array
    foreach ($domains->pricing as $idx => $tld) {
      // Output a row
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>$tld->register[$idx]</td>";
      echo "<td>$tld->transfer->[$idx]</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }

    // Close the table
    echo "</table>";
  }
?>
```

JSON OUTPUT EXAMPLE

```
{
    "currency": {
        "id": "1",
        "code": "USD",
        "prefix": "$",
        "suffix": " USD",
        "format": "2",
        "rate": "1.00000"
    },
    "pricing": {
        "com": {
            "categories": [
                "Popular",
                "gTLD"
            ],
            "addons": {
                "dns": true,
                "email": true,
                "idprotect": true
            },
            "group": "new",
            "register": {
                "1": "9.95",
                "2": "19.90",
                "3": "29.85"
            },
            "transfer": {
                "1": "9.95",
                "2": "15.00",
                "3": "25.00"
            },
            "renew": {
                "1": "9.95",
                "2": "15.00",
                "3": "25.00"
            }
        },
        "net": {
            "categories": [
                "Popular",
                "gTLD"
            ],
            "addons": {
                "dns": false,
                "email": false,
                "idprotect": false
            },
            "group": "sale",
            "register": {
                "1": "9.00"
            },
            "transfer": {
                "1": "11.95"
            },
            "renew": {
                "1": "11.95"
            }
        },
        "org": {
            "categories": [
                "Popular",
                "gTLD"
            ],
            "addons": {
                "dns": false,
                "email": false,
                "idprotect": false
            },
            "group": "hot",
            "register": {
                "1": "11.95"
            },
            "transfer": {
                "1": "11.95"
            },
            "renew": {
                "1": "11.95"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I have got the table PHP stuff totally wrong but as I said, first time for me so that is as far as I got.

The table I am trying to render would be something like:

```
TLD    | REGISTER   |  TRANSFER  |    RENEW
---------------------------------------------
.com   | 1yr (9.95) | 1yr (9.95) |  1yr (9.95)
.co.uk | 1yr (9.95) | 1yr (9.95) |  1yr (9.95)
```

etc....

Comment: Hi James. I notice your posts are rather on the chatty side, and on _Stack Overflow_ the community tends to discourage this. Advance thanks, explicit requests to please help, hopes that someone can help, and so forth are best omitted. Would you kindly refrain from this material? It would save volunteer editors a fair bit of future work. Editing one post takes a minute or two, but multiplied by the hundreds of questions one person can ask, it soon mounts up (and we don't have enough volunteer editors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the elements inside the loop are not arrays, but objects (instances of `stdClass`, specifically). You can continue going through them using the arrow operator:

```
$domains = json_decode($json);
foreach ($domains->pricing as $tld => $attrs) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$tld."</td>";
    echo "<td>1yr (".$attrs->register->{1}.")</td>";
    echo "<td>1yr (".$attrs->transfer->{1}.")</td>";
    echo "<td>1yr (".$attrs->renew->{1}.")</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/H1qdm)

And you can keep going at it the same way. For example, if you need to show all the price options for different years per type, inside the loop you can add this:

```
foreach ($attrs->register as $nYears => $pricePerYear) {
    echo $nYears." yrs: ".$pricePerYear;
}
```

And your other option, which is closer to what you had initially, is setting `true` as the second parameter for `json_decode()`, which will give you an `array` instead of an `stdClass` instance. This code accomplishes the same:

```
$domains = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($domains["pricing"] as $tld => $attrs) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$tld."</td>";
    echo "<td>1yr (".$attrs["register"][1].")</td>";
    echo "<td>1yr (".$attrs["transfer"][1].")</td>";
    echo "<td>1yr (".$attrs["renew"][1].")</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

So you can try working it that way, whichever feels more comfortable for you.

Comment: Thanks mate, had to change a couple of things in my source but it is working! thanks a million! Going to try and work out how to add that additional loop for the other years you supplied as well but thanks for your help on this! :)

Comment: It's no problem! Check the edit, it might be better for you if you prefer working with arrays. Good luck!

Comment: Will have a play mate, think i could be cheeky and ask if could add that other foreach for the other years for me as just tried and broke it haha

Comment: [Check this out](https://3v4l.org/Gd4Bh). Formatting is up to you though :). The `foreach`s are fairly repetitive, just keep giving it a try, seeing what the compiler yells at you and fixing it.